# Access datas based on user role in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to access datas based on user roles in asp.net ?

For example : i have two admins (admin1, admin2) .

In the frontend ,admin1 has full access to datas(view,add,edit,delete  all datas)

while admin2 has limited access to datas(view,add,edit,delete  certain datas alone and not all datas)

thank you

Comment: Roles define privileges. Shouldn't your two users have the different roles, since they have different sets of privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Roles.IsUserInRole method to qualify whether a user is in a role or not then show the corresponding data.

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(<USERNAME>, <ROLE>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code *Ira Rainey* posted to toggle control using code or you could use a **LoginView Control**.

Check the **Displaying Role-Specific Markup With the LoginView Control** section of [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083524/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121405-1.aspx) (go down the page) to get an overview.